# Why is the probability mass function of a transformed discrete random variable summed over the inverse values of the function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random discrete variable with probability mass function (pmf) of $p_X(x) = P(X = x)$. Let $Y = g(X)$ (from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$). Then, why is it that: $$p_Y(y) = \sum_{x \in g^{-1}(y)}p_X(x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $Y =y$ iff $g(X)=y$ iff $X \in g^{-1}(\{y\})$. Hence $P(Y=y)=P(X \in g^{-1}(\{y\})=\sum_{x \in g^{-1}(\{y\})}  P(X=x)$